# Solve this nonlinear matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $M$ and $N$ two invertible square matrices of the same size $n$, consider the equation
$$
\forall i,j, \quad M_{ij}(M^{-1})_{ji} = N_{ij}(N^{-1})_{ji}\ .
$$
Assuming we know $M$, we want to find all matrices $N$ that obey this equation. Obvious solutions are 
$$
N_{ij} = \lambda_i \mu_j M_{ij}\ ,
\\
N_{ij} = \lambda_i \mu_j (M^{-1})_{ji}\ ,
$$
for arbitrary vectors $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$.

But what are all the solutions?

Comment: By checking what happenswith elementary transforms of $M$, the problem reduces to $M=I$.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Reducing the problem to $M=I$ (or $M$ diagonal) would help a lot, but I do not see how to do this.

Comment: Actually, matrices that have zero coefficients, such that $M=I$, allow for more solutions, such as $N$ being triangular. This shows that the problem most probably cannot be easily reduced to $M=I$.

Comment: @SylvainRibault Good point. This observation also answers your question (negatively), doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does answer the question negatively. The wider question is now to find all solutions.

Comment: There are also Hadamard matrices...

Comment: Hadamard matrices are a nice idea, but we need two independent such matrices, and this exists only for certain matrix sizes, if I understand correctly. A related idea is to consider more general orthogonal matrices, then the equation becomes $M_{ij} = \epsilon_{ij} N_{ij}$ with $\epsilon_{ij}\in\{1,-1\}$,

Comment: I have modified the title and text because I have realized that for $n=3$ there are (many) more solutions. Namely, the two types of solutions $N\propto M$ and $N\propto (M^{-1})^T$ seem to be two special points on a line of solutions.

Comment: For more context and details, see this blog post: http://researchpracticesandtools.blogspot.fr/2018/01/on-single-valued-solutions-of.html